# TypeScript with this. parameter

Tags: typescript

I have the code below and keep getting Property 'weatherData' does not exist on type 'XMLHttpRequest'. This is suppose to output the weather in a console.

```
class WeatherService {
    public weatherData;

    public getWeather(callback) {
        let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?API=&APPID=d43debb0b9a3919fef3f0f689e82583e&q=${this.city}`;
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // parse weather data from Ajax call
            this.weatherData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            // invoke callback to notify that we are done
            callback();
        })
        request.open('GET', url);
        request.send();
    }

    constructor(private city: string) { }
}

// create instance of weather service for Seattle
let service = new WeatherService('Seattle');

// invoke the service to get weather data for Seattle
service.getWeather(() => {
    console.log(service.weatherData);
});
```

Comment: do you really want to add `weatherData` to the request object? because the `this` in the `request.addEventListener('load')` callback refers to `request`, not the `WeatherService` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is `request` in the `addEventListener` callback, but you can override that by using arrow function syntax for your callback so that `this` will be your class instance instead:

```
request.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // parse weather data from Ajax call
    this.weatherData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    // invoke callback to notify that we are done
    callback();
})
```

Comment: Doesn't `this` refer to the `getWeather` method in that case, not the class? The way he wants to `console.log` it, it seems he wants to add `weatherData` to the service class.

Comment: No, `this` will be the `service` class instance because `getWeather` is called as `service.getWeather`.

Comment: Yeah the arrow method worked perfectly thanks again.